# Table and NonlinearModelFit

Tags: fitting, list-manipulation

I am trying to make data and fit it tp a power law model. but it doesn't work. I don't know what the problem is.

```
mample = 1.05295;
sigma = 0.509317;
model = a*x^c
data = 
  Table[
    {x, mample*(1/(sigma*Sqrt[2*Pi]))*Exp[-(1/2)*(((x)/sigma)^(2))]}, 
    {x,0, 2.1, 0.05}];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {a, c}, x]
Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 2.1}, Epilog -> Point[m], PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Change the plot command to `Plot[Normal[nlm], {x, 0, 2.1}, PlotRange -> All]` (`Point[m]` isn't defined)

Answer (score 1):

The model `a*x^c` doesn't fit the data very well.

Try for example a rational approximation

```
model = (a + b x^2)/(1 + c x^2 + d x^4)
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {a, b, c, d} , x]
Show[{Plot[Normal[nlm], {x, 0, 2.1}, PlotRange -> All],ListPlot[data]}]
```

[image]

to get better approximation.

Comment: Thanks Neumann!